# Keeping feature branch up to date

Tags: git, git-flow

Recently we started using Gitflow for our projects and we are experiencing some problems we cannot wrap our head around.

We have the default setup with the `master`, `develop`, `feature/xyz` and `hotfix` branches. So assume I am working on a long term feature, let's call this `feature/long-time`. My colleagues are in the mean time working on `feature/short-time`. Imagine that after some work, they will commit `feature/short-time` in to `develop` and I occasionally commit `feature/long-term` so they can see my progress and it is safely backed up.

Naturally, the `feature/long-term` cannot ignore the `develop` branch for too long or it will fall behind. So how can we periodically sync the changes to the `develop` branch to the `feature/long-term` branch?

I have come across two options:

- Simply doing `git merge` every now and then. However, I feel like this is not really correct according to Gitflow's philosophy
- I have seen `git rebase` a few times now too, however this seems to work only if you do not push your changes to the remote branch, is that correct?

To wrap up: how do I correctly keep my feature branche(s) up to date?

Comment: Merging from `develop` into your feature branch is absolutely fine and the only good choice here (you cannot rebase for the reasons you’ve given). This is even given as an example in the original [introductory article](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) (see the second feature branch, somewhere down, they merge the develop branch in).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This brings back again the merge vs rebase discussion, which has been tackled multiple times. For a long story, you can check [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing).
As you correctly said, it is not good to rebase if you're pushing your branch, as changing your git history would make you force the push, which is not good for a daily basis, but rebasing in general is "cleaner" than a merge, so:

- If you **have to** push your branch often enough for whatever reason (code reviews, CI builds of the branch, etc.) your best option is a `merge`.
- If you can fully work in an independent manner avoiding pushing your changes very often, probably `rebase` is a better option.

In the case that you are working in a very long task, even if rebase is your main strategy, merging from time to time is a good idea because:
   1. Your changes are backed up in the remote repository from time to time.
   2. It is not practical to rebase a big number of commits, as the diff is calculated commit by commit, whilst in a merge it is calculated for all the commits at the same time. This means that for a large number of commits you might need to resolve an unnecessary big amount of conflicts that can be reduced to one per file with a merge.

To sum up, I would suggest rebasing most of the times to keep a clean repository, but merging from time to time to keep a backup of your branch in the repo and lighting future rebases.